# When to use the 'new' keyword to instantiate objects

Tags: java, android

Im learning how to program android apps at the moment. Im currently messing around with it.

Right now I'm creating a custom Toast where I create a layout in XML and convert that XML into java (using the `LayoutInflater` class) so that the layout appears in the `Toast` and then disappears after 2-3 seconds (using `Toast.LENGTH_LONG`).

I was watching a youtube video about that and I noticed something. The person said he instantiated an object when he wrote this:

`LayoutInflater inflater= getLayoutInflator();`

but i thought you need to use the `new` keyword to instantiate/create objects so why didn't he use it. I then tried writing

`LayoutInflater inflater = new LayoutInflater();`

and got the following error:

```
Cannot instantiate the type LayoutInflater.
```

I know that you get this error when trying to create an object from an interface but I don't think the layoutinflater is an interface but a class.

Comment: You should show the video or post a relevant example. Although I don't know why there are so many down votes.

Comment: With the expression `LayoutInflater inflater= getLayoutInflator()` *you* don't instantiate (create) an object. Instead it's the function `getLayoutInflator` which creates (instantiates) the object, and return a reference to the object to you, and you take this reference and assign it to your variable `inflater`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg are you sure getLayoutInflater actually creates a new instance ? My understanding was that it returns a reference to the same  LayoutInflater that the Activity uses to inflate its UI...

Comment: @2Dee Either `getLayoutInflator` or a function it calls. Some function somewhere in the call-chain creates the object, but the object isn't created by the simple assignment to `inflater`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I've been looking at the source, but Window is abstract and I can't find the exact subclass of it that Activity is using. Taking PhoneWindow as example, it seems to instantiate an inflater only once in its own constructor, and calling getLayoutInflater will return the same one, not a new instance.

Comment: @2Dee The point isn't exactly where the object is created, the point is that the assignment itself doesn't create anything, and that whoever told the OP that the shown assignment created a new object was wrong.

Answer (score 3):

LayoutInflater is an [abstract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) class. Therefore, it cannot be instantiated.

Comment: ohh. I forgot all about that. Thanks for the help

Comment: Upvote for the link to the abstract keyword documentation ! :)

Answer (score 2):

`LayoutInflater` is an **abstract** class, so you can't instantiate one like that. But you can do the following :

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
```

or this

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
      (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

If you are in an `Activity` class, you can also call `getLayoutInflater()`.